# CSS apply class where parent doesn't have a class

Tags: html, css

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish and might be on the wrong track.

I have css for all buttons on my page

```
button, input[type=button]{
  background-color: red;
}
```

The goal is to apply this class to all buttons on the site, unless the button is inside a parent with class "clean".  Parent could be couple elements higher.

```
<div>
  <button>Class Applied</button>
</div>

<div class="clean">  <- Parent 1
  <div>  <- Parent 2
    <div>  <- Parent 3
      <button>Class NOT Applied</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

first 2 buttons should not have style applied to them: http://codepen.io/amstech/pen/PNQQBo

Comment: Just a note on terminologies. `Parent 3` is the only parent your `button` has. `Parent 1` and `Parent 2` are the `ancestors`. Also you're not applying a `class` you're applying a `style`.

Comment: I have only jQuery solution for this. There is no full CSS solution to fit exactly to your scenario. You should change your way (like using .styled-button instead of using .clean), fix your code for using initial or use scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Add this anywhere below your first block of code and choose the type of styling you want for the .clean buttons. It should work (tested).

```
.clean button {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: not going to work. i might not have access to the button.  it could be an angular directive. so i can just surround the directive with a div and class clean and my style will not be applied

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
div.clean button { 
    // if parent has clean class
    background-color: red;
}

div:not(.clean) button { 
    // if parent has not clean class
    background-color: white;
}

div.clean div button { 
    // button has any parent div with .clean class
    // and atleast one subparented div
    background-color: red;
}

div.clean div:not(.clean) button { 
    // button has any parent div with .clean class
    // and atleast one subparented div which has not .clean class
    background-color: red;
}

div.clean div div button { 
    // button has any parent div with .clean class
    // and atleast 2 subparented divs, now set the color as white
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: this is too specific.  the parent might not be a div, and it could be 5-10 layers up.

Comment: Than you should be OK with the first 2 styles

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxxohLab/1/)

#### HTML

```
<div>
  <div class="clean">
    <!--Assume this is a directive and I don't know anything about depth of the element-->
    <div>
      <button>
        1. no class applied
      </button>
    </div>
    <button>
      2. no class applied
    </button>
  </div>
  <!-- and this button is on my site and i have control over it-->
  <button>
    3. class applied
  </button>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
*:not(.clean) button,
*:not(.clean) input[type=button] {
  background-color: red;
}

*.clean button,
*.clean input[type=button] {
  background-color: initial;
}
```

Comment: what is the point of reseting background-color to initial. it was not supposed to be set to red in the first place?